# How to adapt the use of ActionBar.TabListener

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-actionbar

I want to make a view that is composed of some textViews and buttons in the head of the view, and some tabs below these textViews and buttons. I am using for that a class that is implementing ActionBar.TabListener, but the problem is that tabs stay above in the view and textViews (and buttons) come below them, which is the opposite of what I want.
I think that the interface "ActionBar.TabListener" is not suitable as a solution to this problem. Any suggestions to fix that problem ?

Here's my file XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/red" >
<LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingTop="5dip"
     android:paddingBottom="5dip">
     <ImageView
         android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/dbm"
         />
 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
     <Button 
         android:id="@+id/btn_creer"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/ajt_LC"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         />
     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btn_supp"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/sup_LC"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         />
 </LinearLayout>
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
 <LinearLayout 
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
     <TextView 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:text="@string/lab_total"
     />
     <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/total"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     />
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's my code JAVA file:

```
public class FragmentsSliderActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

private MyPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "TAB 1", "TAB 2"};
String login;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    this.mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());       
    viewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);       

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Show your code and the result

Comment: actionbar tabs will always be placed on top. You may want to use sliding tabs which can be placed anywhere.

Comment: @Harry Can you give me an example of these sliding tabs ?

Comment: download project given [Here](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic) you will see it already have added some content above tabs.